# Get the file from project folder

Tags: c#

I have SQL scripts in folder of project, I need to run the script using c#.

```
FileInfo file=new FileInfo(@"Data/SQLscript.sql");
```

Which couldn't access by c#. Anybody have answers , please help me to find answer.

Comment: *Which couldn't access by c#,* any errors/stacktrace?

Comment: why a forward slash?

Comment: Specify the full path, which FileInfo expects as a string: `FileInfo(@"c:\Data\SQLscript.sql")` . Also please see the [FAQ]s and [ask] tips, always include the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was 
`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+@"Data\SQLQuery.sql";`